# Passing context in android

Tags: android, android-activity, hashmap, adapter, android-context

a newbie in this would like some advice on know how to pass context of a class in the given example.

In class AA have something like below,where listtext is a listtype hashmap.

```
 List<HashMap<String, String>> listText = atext.get();

 SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Context,listText,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);
```

The thing is, Context is supposed to be the place where you want to display the result in the given scenario.

And that class would be A1, having a Edittext widget.

So the question here is how to get the context of the class A1 passed here ?
to get the result in the Edittext widget of class A1.

Might be a rookie question so please be gentle.

Thanks for the response

Comment: i don't get you, but `A1.this` return context for you.`AA` is `Activity` class?

Comment: Nope! its just a simple class

Comment: so you can pass context to constructor of `AA` class

Comment: Which one is `Activity` class .

Comment: A1 is the activity class. while AA is a simple class.

Answer (score 0):

Change -

```
 List<HashMap<String, String>> listText = atext.get();

 SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Context,listText,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);
```

to

```
 List<HashMap<String, String>> listText = atext.get();

 SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),listText,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor of class AA, when initializing AA in A1, pass the context of A1. In class `AA`:

```
private Context context;
public AA(Context a1){
    this.context = a1;
}
```

In class `A1`:

```
AA aa = new AA(getContext());
```

Then you can use

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context,listText,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);
```

Comment: I'm sure your mean of `A1` in constructor is `Context` (Context a1)

Comment: @ shayan pourvatan Yes,it is. Actually if `A1` is an `Activity`, it's a `Context` as well.

Comment: so what should go in the place of "Context" ??Mean in the syntax of Simpleadapter .

Comment: if you change A1 to Context is more better, because maybe OP want's use this class with another context.

Comment: @ shayan pourvatan Sure.

Comment: @JaneWi.S then you can use context for `Context`, with (lower case `c`)

Comment: @shayan pourvatan ya got that but in the other class class A1 having the widget ..does'nt provide with the getContext().Can you please walk me through this.!!

Comment: what you want with `getContext()`?

Comment: want to diaplay the data in the textview of classA1

Comment: @JaneWi.S use `A1.this` for getting context as a said before on comment